# Which one to use for calling REST in dojo

Tags: rest, dojo

i need to call the REST API which is provided by the google maps engine as in the link

https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/requests

i need to make the request to these API using dojo framework

Please let me know which one to use dojo/request, dojo/request/xhr.. Which one i have to use.. and

How can we decide which one to used based on what?

Thanks
Chiru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be looking at [`dojo/request/script`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/script.html). The reason for this is that you're trying to load cross-domain data, and browsers block XHR requests that are cross domain.

If you don't want to use JSONP (it's kind of a "hack" that is commonly used on the web), the Google maps API also support setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so that means cross domain requests to the Google maps API will work (look at the Google maps API docs for more information). The only drawback is that this does only work in modern browsers afaik.

Comment: this support only the GET method.. if need to POST some data to google maps engine i can not use this right?

Comment: That's true, you can only use GET. If you also need post then you should be using `dojo/request/xhr`. I don't know if you need to do anything extra, but as far as I can read Google allows external calls (read more at: https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/requests#javascript_cross-domain_requests). However this means that Google needs to set a header in their requests and I don't know if they allow all hosts automatically or not (you might have to find that out in their documentation).